# How to receive xml nodes inside a time range by using xquery

Tags: date, xquery

I have an xml with something like that inside

```
<SFEvents>
  <EventList>
    <Event>
      <ID>1111</ID>
      <Type>Measurement</Type>
      <TimeStamp>2015-09-28T09:50:27.514</TimeStamp>
      <Space>Main_area</Space>
      <SourceID>Thermometer_3</SourceID>
      <Content>
        <Measurement>
          <!-- From B2MML standard (OpSegmentDataType) -->
          <ID/>
          <Description>Temperature of a power resistance</Description>
          <Value>
            <ValueString>100</ValueString>
            <UnitOfMeasure>oC</UnitOfMeasure>
          </Value>
        </Measurement>
      </Content>
    </Event>
<Event>..</Event>
...
</EventList>
```

with many events and I currently try to receive with xquery all the Event nodes that have their Timestamp inside a time range

I use this code

```
all_xmls_String=session.execute("xquery for $b in  doc('CIDEMdb/CIDEM.xml') 
let $date_string as xs:string :=$b/SFEvents/EventList/Event/TimeStamp/data() 
let $date as xs:dateTime := xs:dateTime($date_string)  
where $date ge xs:dateTime('"+startdate+"') and $date le 
xs:dateTime('"+enddate+"')  return $b/SFEvents/EventList");
```

but I receive this error
Cannot cast xs:untypedAtomic+ to xs:string: ("2015-09-28T09:50:27.514", ...).

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are iterating over the `EventList` document, which has a cardinality of 1, while selecting `$b/SFEvents/EventList/Event/TimeStamp/data()`, a sequence of `TimeStamp` values, and assigning it to a variable that expects a single value. Your query also returns an `EventList`, but you say you want to return `Event`s.

There are several ways to do this, but the easiest way given your existing query it to simply iterate over the `Event` elements instead, select the single `TimeStamp` value, and then return the selected `Event`s.

```
for $b in doc('CIDEMdb/CIDEM.xml')//SFEvents/EventList/Event
let $date_string as xs:string :=$b/TimeStamp/data() 
let $date as xs:dateTime := xs:dateTime($date_string)  
where $date ge xs:dateTime('"+startdate+"') and $date le xs:dateTime('"+enddate+"')  
return $b
```